# SQL join statement

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables I need to join together and I'm unsure how to do it.  I'm still trying to learn how join works and I know there are a bunch of different kinds.  Here are my tables:

```
laser    feature1   feature2   feature3
laser1   1          1          0
laser2   1          0          1
laser3   1          1          0


feature_name   feature_text
Feature #1     Text 1
Feature #2     Text 2
Feature #3     Text 3
```

How do I join these two tables together so I get only the feature_names and feature_texts where there is a 1 in the top table?

Comment: What/where is the join condition?

Comment: Is this a one to one, one to many, or many to many relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a better structure:

```
laser (Table)
-------------
laser_name, laser_id

feature (Table)
---------------
feature_name, feature_texts, feature_id

feature_laser (Table)
---------------------
laser_id, feature_id
```

**Edit**

If you want to see what lasers are associated with feature_id = 1, then you can join like this:

```
select laser_name from laser
    inner join feature_laser on feature_laser.laser_id = laser.laser_id
where feature_id = 1;
```

If you want to see what features are associated with laser_id = 1, then you can join like this:

```
select feature_name from features
    inner join feature_laser on feature_laser.feature_id = features.feature_id
where laser_id = 1;
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  Thanks, watcher.  What would be my JOIN statement?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming feature1, fetaure2, etc. are columns, you aren't going to be able to do this with a join in a graceful way, because your database isn't normalized properly. You need to lose those columns and make a laser_feature linking table to get a proper many-to-many relationship first.

Comment: That's what the top table is supposed to be.  How should it be structured?